# Insert constraint failed nFOREIGN KEY constraint failed While Seeding Data

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, ef-code-first

I am trying to Seed some sample Data

```
public class Condition 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Entity 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ConditionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Condition Condition { get; set; }
}
```

and in my Seed method..

```
 protected override void Seed(AppContext context)
 {
      Condition condition1 = new Condition();
      condition1.Name = "Cond1";
      Entity.Entity newEntity1 = new Entity.Entity();
      newEntity1.Name = "Test1";
      newEntity1.Condition = condition1;
      context.Entities.Add(newEntity1);

      Condition condition2 = new Condition();
      condition2.Name = "Cond2";
      Entity.Entity newEntity2 = new Entity.Entity();
      newEntity2.Name = "Test Entity 2";
      newEntity2.Condition = condition2;
      context.Entities.Add(newEntity2);
      context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

I am getting this Exception constraint failed FOREIGN KEY constraint failed, I couldn't figure out what wrong I am doing here.

I tried calling   context.SaveChanges() after first insertion too and it went fine. but the error appreared only after second context.SaveChanges() only.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void Seed(AppContext context)
 {
      Condition condition1 = new Condition();
      condition1.Id=1; 
      condition1.Name = "Cond1";
      Entity.Entity newEntity1 = new Entity.Entity();
      newEntity1.Name = "Test1";
      newEntity1.ConditionId=1
      newEntity1.Condition = condition1;
      context.Entities.Add(newEntity1);

      Condition condition2 = new Condition();
      condition2.Id=2
      condition2.Name = "Cond2";
      Entity.Entity newEntity2 = new Entity.Entity();
      newEntity2.Name = "Test Entity 2";
      newEntity2.ConditionId=2; 
      newEntity2.Condition = condition2;
      context.Entities.Add(newEntity2);
      context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Hope This works..